# Lower bound seems not working with covariance

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
class Animal
class Cat extends Animal
class BlackCat extends Cat
class MyOption[+A](val x: A) {
      def get(): A = x
      def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B = {
        if (x != null) x else default
      }
}

object ThirdParty {
  def getAnimal : MyOption[Animal]= new MyOption[Cat](null)
}

object MyOptionRunner {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val opt3: Animal = ThirdParty.getAnimal.getOrElse(new BlackCat)
    println(opt3)
    }
}
```

I am surprised that `val opt3: Animal = ThirdParty.getAnimal.getOrElse(new BlackCat)` can pass the compiling.

The type of `ThirdParty.getAnimal` is Myption[Cat],then the call is equivalent to 
`Myption[Cat].getOrElse(new BlackCat),`it doesn't conform to the definition of getOrElse, A is Cat and B is BlackCat here, which breaks B>:A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val opt3: Animal = ThirdParty.getAnimal.getOrElse(new BlackCat)
```

`B` is not `BlackCat`; the type of `B` will be the most specific type that conforms to the specification required. Since the argument is `new BlackCat`, we know that `B >: BlackCat`. By the requirement of `getOrElse`, we know that `B >: Cat`. The most specific type that satisfies both of these requirements is, naturally, `Cat`.

Comment: Thanks @silvio-mayolo. Then, anything(type of Any) can be argument of `getOrElse`,eg:`ThirdParty.getAnimal.getOrElse(1)`

Comment: That's right. `ThirdParty.getAnimal.getOrElse(1)` will return an argument of type `Any`. I just personally tested it; it works exactly like you said.